# Iterating between methods of controls in a form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've got a number of panels, each of which with a number of groupboxes containing various type of controls.
Once in a while, I need to update the texts and values of the controls with fresh data, but I would not like to fire up events connected to every control.
So I'd like to removehandlers for each of the involved controls, change the texts and values, and then add the handlers once again.

I know I have to use CallByName, but its syntax is somewhat obscure to me.
Anyone would like to have a look at the provided meta-code below (example for selectedindexchanged methods) and provide the necessary correction, I'd appreciate.

```
For Each mpanel In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (mpanel) Is MetroPanel Then
        For Each gbox In mpanel.controls
            If TypeOf gbox Is GroupBox Then
                For Each ctrl In gbox.controls
                    If TypeOf (ctrl) Is MetroComboBox Then
                        Dim methodName As String = ctrl.name.ToString & "_Selectedindexchanged"
                        Dim method = CallByName(ctrl, methodName, CallType.Method)
                        RemoveHandler DirectCast(ctrl, MetroComboBox).SelectedIndexChanged, method
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: First you should mention what is wrong with your approach. What error/exception you get or what doesn't work? [`CallByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function) is a VBA function, i don't even know if it works in winforms. It's certainly not the .NET way to do what you want. Why you can't use the properties of `MetroComboBox` to update it's values?

Comment: CallByName is a vb.net method as explained here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.callbyname?view=netframework-4.7.2 and certainly works in winforms.
Don't understand what you mean by using the Class properties for updating a quantity of controls.

Comment: I dont understand why you want to use reflection or whatever this obscure method is. Why you can't update the control directly? For example: `DirectCast(ctrl, MetroComboBox).SelectedIndex = 0`. If you want to call another method you also don't need reflection, just call it: `UpdateMyComboBox(DirectCast(ctrl, MetroComboBox))`(for example). `CallByName` exists for compatibility reasons, it's legacy VB stuff which you should avoid

Comment: I don't need to update the control. I need to Remove a specific event handler from each member of a collection of controls

Comment: Why you have one event handler for each control? You could handle all `MetroComboBox` `SelectedIndexChanged` events in one handler. The passed `source` argument is the concrete control. Then you don't need to determine the handler from the name here. Then you also don't need this `RemoveHandler`+`AddHandler` in the loop but only once at the beginning and end.

Comment: I have one event handler for each control because each MetroComboBox have different behaviour and items. And I want to avoid events misfiring in specific parts of my code.

Comment: I appreciated your explanation, I get it, and for the future I will do as suggested. Unfortunately I went down another road. For discussion sake, is there a way I can free myself from the hole I trapped myself, other than your suggestion? If not, please promote your comment as answer.

Comment: `MetroComboBox` should derives from standard `ComboBox`, that mean it should have `SelectionChangeCommitted` event. Event raises only when combobox selection made by user, which mean you can freely update combobox values programmatically without raising selection event.

Comment: Another approach **used by all winforms developers**: boolean flag. In all events use this flag to check is update made automatically, if not execute event logic, if automatic - do nothing. Then when you want refresh data set flag to true and back to false after refreshing is done.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio. The SelectionChangeCommited event is the exact solution at my problem. Please mark as an answer.

Comment: How did you use the `SelectionChangeCommited` event?

Comment: I just replaced all occurences of SelectedIndexChanged with SelectionChangeCommited and I also noticed a considerable speed increase in the management of my form.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to remove eventhandler by name by using the following syntax:

```
For Each mpanel In Me.Controls
If TypeOf (mpanel) Is MetroPanel Then
    For Each gbox In mpanel.controls
        If TypeOf gbox Is GroupBox Then
            For Each ctrl In gbox.controls
                If TypeOf (ctrl) Is MetroComboBox Then
                    Dim methodName As String = ctrl.name.ToString & "_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    Dim method As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = Type.GetType("MyClass").GetMethod(methodName)
                    RemoveHandler DirectCast(ctrl, MetroComboBox).SelectedIndexChanged, Addressof method
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Next